# How to get the current webview object in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, android-instrumentation

I am using Datadog to track user activity in my app. Now I need to instrument webviews. After [initializing datadog's sdk](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/android/?tab=kotlin#configuration) , its documentation says that I have to call the following code snippet:

`DatadogEventBridge.setup(webView)`

that is, I have to call the static method **setup** and pass to it a WebView object. But the problem is: my application has many objects like this (many webviews). Do I have to put this code in every class that has a WebView attribute? Or is it possible in somehow use a callback function which is called whenever a webview is instatiated, the in this callback I'd call DatadogEventBridge.setup(webView)?

I tried using lifecycle callbacks and then receive an Acitivty for every "onResume" method in order to check whether this activity has a webview. But it went wrong.

Comment: "Or is it possible in somehow use a callback function which is called whenever a webview is instatiated" -- sorry, there is no such callback. "But it went wrong" -- without a [mcve], we cannot assist you with that problem. "But the problem is: my application has many objects like this (many webviews)" -- perhaps you should be using inheritance, composition, or other approaches for reducing the number of distinct pieces of code that deal with a `WebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with the Datadog Sdk but you could try creating your own WebView by extending the standard one - and then replace all the other WebViews with it. Here's how it'll look like in practice:

```
class TrackableWebView : WebView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int)
        : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    init {
        DatadogEventBridge.setup(this)
    }
}
```

I think we can assume that the Sdk will be initialized much earlier than the WebViews, so there should be no problem with calling the             `DatadogEventBridge.setup(this)` before the Sdk is initialized.

Then if you use the XML layouts you just replace standard WebView with your custom one:

```
<com.example.TrackableWebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Great! I hadn't thought of that, I'll try it!

Comment: But I still have a question: to get the webview objects, I do something like this: ```val myWebView = myActivityBinding.myWebView``` and it already comes with the type WebView from Android framework. How could I change this in order to assign a CustomWebView type (that inherits from WebView) to my webview object??

Comment: I updated my answer, you just replace the WebView in the XML layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebViewClient to intercept when a WebView is created and then call the `DatadogEventBridge.setup(webView)` from there.
You can create a class that extends WebViewClient and then add it to each of your WebViews using the `WebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient wvc)` method.

```
public class DatadogWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, URL);
        DatadogEventBridge.setup(view);
    }
}
```